# LinearDiscriminantAnalysis - Single column output from .transform(X)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, pycharm

I have been successfully playing around with replicating one of the [sklearn tutorials](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html#example-decomposition-plot-pca-vs-lda-py) using the iris dataset in PyCharm using Python 2.7.  However, when trying to repeat this with my own data I have been encountering an issue. I have been importing data from a .csv file using 'np.genfromtxt', but for some reason I keep getting a single column output for X_r2 (see below), when I should get a 2 column output. I have therefore replaced my data with some randomly generated variables to post onto SO, and I am still getting the same issue.

I have included the 'problem' code below, and I would be interested to know what I have done wrong. I have extensively used the debugging features in PyCharm to check that the type and shape of my variables are similar to the original sklearn example, but it did not help me with the problem. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

y = np.random.randint(2, size=500)
X = np.random.randint(1, high=1000, size=(500, 6))
target_names = np.array([['XX'], ['YY']])
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `y` in the example you posted has values of 0, 1 and 2 while yours only has values of 0 and 1. This change achieves what you want:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

y = np.random.randint(3, size=500)
X = np.random.randint(1, high=1000, size=(500, 6))
target_names = np.array([['XX'], ['YY']])
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That does indeed fix the problem. However, I only had two targets as it represents my current problem. Would that suggest that this method only works with a minimum of 3 targets?

Comment: I don't know what the method actually does. To ask your follow up question which seems to be about understanding the statistics rather than the programming, you might be better off at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice.